# Looking to map an Azure Fileshare as a mapped network drive on an Azure Windows VM via another machine/Custom Script Execution

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli

I'm attempting to provision a Windows VM and I need to map some Azure fileshares to  drives for the VM user that will be interacting with the VM.

I've been trying to make "az vm extension set"/Custom Script Execution work for me by calling some PowerShell scripts to setup the mapping to the fileshare, but since the process runs as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, the mappings aren't working, obviously.  I've tried to switch user contexts in my scripts via having an intermediate script that changes context to my VM user and then calling another script that does the work, but that doesn't seem to be working.

```
$scriptFile = $args[0]
$username = $args[1]
$password = $args[2]
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, 
$securePassword
Start-Process Powershell.exe -Credential $credential $scriptFile
```

Unfortunately it seems nothing gets run in the $scriptFile that I call, and I can't get any errors out of standard out/err, so I'm at a loss as to how this can be done.

Certainly someone out there has had to run scripts as another user via the Custom Script Execution method before, I'm hoping they happen to read this post.

Is there a way to set what user the Custom Script Execution runs as?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way of setting a user under which script extension runs.

You also should use `-PassThru` and `-Wait` and\or `-RedirectStandardError\-RedirectStandardInput` to your command invocation. Also, add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your commands to propagate errors.

Comment: Edited script to use:

"Start-Process Powershell.exe -PassThru -Wait -ErrorAction Stop -RedirectStandardError c:\temp\err.log -RedirectStandardOut c:\temp\out.log -Credential $credential $scriptFile "

err.log and out.log are created, but are 0 bytes each.  Everything that goes into the secondary script goes into a vacuum it seems.  :(

When I run the script locally, of course everything works fine.